# How to change programs used to handle files in Calibre in Debian

Tags: debian, file-opening, calibre

I have recently installed Calibre, and it works great, however I have some problems with handling of files by this program:

- Folders open in `baobab`. To open folder I just need to click on a book and then select: `Path:    Click to open`.
- CBR files open in print-preview.

Gobal file associations are sensible (I have checked `~HOME/.config/mimeapps.list`) and cbr files open properly in nautilus.

So questions are:

- How does Calibre detect file associations.
- How to change those associations.

I use i3 window manager.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing though callibre code I found that Calibre uses `QDesktopServices.openUrl` from QT toolkit.

Which in turns uses `xdg-open` utility, which was misconfigured. I have no idea why `nautilus` and `thunar` launched proper programs.